# How to monitor SNMP in ELK SET

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, heartbeat, metricbeat

I need to get the snmp monitoring details into ELK stack.

Can anyone give me a reference or guide me on how to do that.

How to get that data to logstash?

Comment: Have you checked this community beat? https://github.com/isalgueiro/otilio

Comment: community beat means filebeat,logstash beat? i am new to this elk... i have not installed anything in that snmp machine... how can i get data to logstash without installing anything in that snmp machine

Comment: thanks @Val for responding please help me how to do

Comment: Do you still need help?